# Best practice, where to put request_mem_region

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I have two drivers code, in the former one the function `request_mem_region` is called during the device `probe`, in the latter is called during the device `open`, of course you have to call the `release_mem_regione` function taking into account the request function position, but i was wondering which are the pros and cons between these two choices. Any suggest?

Comment: Where/when does the driver perform `ioremap()` and `iounmap()`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the region is being used. If it is only needed while the device is open, then it makes sense to put it in open. If the device is constantly working in the background, even if it is not open, then it will need to be mapped in probe. Basically, request it for the smallest scope that is required for your device's needs.

Putting it in probe, even if only needed while it is open, won't always cause problems, but it does mean you're eating up memory/address space that you don't have to. (edit: I forgot, this doesn't perform the mapping just reserves it, so it isn't really an issue.)

Putting it in open can lead to more complexity - for example, you need to make sure that it only gets mapped once, even if the device can be opened by two different processes at once. Not a hard problem to solve, but something that can be overlooked when learning to write modules and working from example code.